# Subdivision tears and cleaning up edges

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I would really appreciate some advice about cleaning up edges. I feel that when you start adding more complexity to a model and use edge loops it can get really complicated so I want to be able to close the edge loop without wrapping it around the entire object.

In image 1 I created a cube subdivided it, bevelled the edges. Then I selected only the top row of faces (used shift-H to isolate) and extruded over and over to create the hollow edge. I used loop cut to clean up. I can see I have edges that should be closed and are not but the render and surface looks good.

In image 2 I used the same method on the side of the cube at the bottom but now I run into big trouble with lots of tears. In image 3 you can see all of the edge loops that are not closed up.

In image 4 you can see that I added a few edges and it resolved the issue but I am pretty sure I will not go to modelling heaven for the way I cleaned it up.

[Here is a link to the file I am using.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w6dgy8-xhRhjDnDeU6RTPWdY2YMQc8QB)

If anyone can point me in the direction of cleaning up edges or the rules I would be very appreciative or if you could show me how to clean up the edges. This cube is just me practising and not needed for anything.

Image 1
[image: Subdivided square cut into square showing edges]

Image 2
[image: Subdivided square cut into square showing tears]

Image 3
[image: Subdivided square cut into square showing edges]

Image 4
[image: Botched clean up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your topology. You have N-gons and triangles. Stick to rectangles so the subdivision can work properly. Use MatCap's for a better view of lightning around the edges when adding new loop cuts so you dont have to go to modeling hell.

I have fixed your cube for you. I'm still using Blender 2.79 so you can import the fbx from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_hVeMLHYu2jdWg9_t7FFv98-NyJLxZTO/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Firstly thank you AzulShiva. I am able to do what you have done but I was wondering if there was a way to not have loop cuts around the entire object as each detail you add, add lots of faces. I was wondering if there was a way to 'tie them up' for want of a better word.

Comment: No. Loopcuts around the entire model is the way it's done. You cannot Subdivide, Bevel, have smooth shading or do any of the good stuff on a model with triangles and n-gons. You can manually remove faces (or with the Decimate Modifier) only if you use flat shading but there's no point really.

Comment: I assume you are creating the shape for a game because otherwise you shouldn't worry about poly count. Make a new question asking how you can reduce the poly count on the object with smooth shading and I will teach you a neat trick. This is a 604 Poly object: https://imgur.com/a/a98LYPi

Comment: Thank you again AzulShiva. I model for fun but like to export to Unreal and keep count down for that but I normally use decimate. No it really was a complexity thing. Once you start adding lots of details here and there the edges can mount up. However, if you have a neat trick other than decimate, I will add another question.

Comment: Modern engines can render millions of polygons without effort. The bottle neck will always be someplace else. Unless you intend on rendering thousands of these cubes you really don't need to worry but go ahead and post  your question